# AttributeError : 'module' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, django

I'm currently going through the official tutorial provided on Django's documentation site, and have encountered an AttributeError. Here's the code I'm working with :

'polls' is the name of my application.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

\polls\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^blog/', include('Blog.urls')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError at /polls

'module' object has no attribute 'index'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'module' object has no attribute 'index'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\Django\mysite\polls\urls.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  F:\Python 2.7\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.5
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\manoj\\Desktop\\Django\\mysite',
 'F:\\Python 2.7\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'F:\\Python 2.7\\DLLs',
 'F:\\Python 2.7\\lib',
 'F:\\Python 2.7\\lib\\plat-win',
 'F:\\Python 2.7\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'F:\\Python 2.7',
 'F:\\Python 2.7\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 26 Jun 2014 04:44:51 +0530
```

What seems to be the problem with my code ?

---

EDIT 1:

I replaced the line

```
from polls import views
```

with

```
from polls.views import index
```

However, now I get a NameError:

```
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

name 'views' is not defined
```

in the 6th line of my /polls/urls.py source code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls.views import index

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

Comment: There could be some conflict with the package name. Just try changing `from polls import views` to `from polls.views import index`

Comment: Now I'm getting a NameError. I have edited my original post above to include the details of the error that I encountered.

Answer (score 1):

`views.py` should be inside `polls/views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```